# How to remember/cache or specify private key passphrase for Ansible

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, ansible, configuration-management

Just starting out with Ansible, I have set up an Asible user on the client machine and created a set of keys from OpenSSL. I am running Ansible under my own account. I have specified the user and private key file in the Ansible configuration. I want the remote commands to run as this user and this user to sudo to do commands requiring elevation.

```
/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

private_key_file = /etc/ansible/pka/confman.crt
remote_user = confman
```

Commands such as this do not ask for passphrases after initial entry of passphrase:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

The following prompt for a passphrase every time I run them:

```
ansible all -m ping -b
Enter passphrase for key '/etc/ansible/private_keys/confman.crt':
(success)

ansible all -m ping --sudo
Enter passphrase for key '/etc/ansible/private_keys/confman.crt':
(success)

ansible all -a "cat /etc/redhat-release"
Enter passphrase for key '/etc/ansible/private_keys/confman.crt':
(success)
```

Why?

Is there any way to set the passphrase? Is there a more secure way? I plan to run ansible remotely and via cron and via other automation tools where entering a passphrase is not an option.

As context, I have never needed to SSH between Linux servers, always from a Windows machine using tools such as putty, RoyalTS and mRemoteNG so my ssh knowledge is... sparse. I assume I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feature is called `ssh-agent`:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent`  # you might have agent already running so this might not be needed
$ ssh-add /etc/ansible/private_keys/confman.crt
```

now ansible should be able to find the key in agent and authenticate without asking for passphrase every time. [From: Documentation: Your first commands](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html#your-first-commands)

Comment: Hindsight makes this looks wonderfully simple. But I googled the hell out of this expecting it to be an ansible variable. Still no explanation why it was cached for some commands and not others.

Comment: So in a typical real-life scenario you need to configure Vagrant to configure ansible to configure and use ssh-agent? JESUS CHRIST WHY

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski no. You configure ssh to use a key. What is in the stack above really does not matter.